# Get first DOM element in list

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array of DOM elements, not in DOM order. How can I get the first one i.e. the one that occurs the first in the DOM?

Would be nice if jQuery can help here.

Thanks

Comment: Do they all have the same parent element?

Comment: `$('selector:first')`..???

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar - I haven't got a selector, just an array

Comment: Why the downvote? Please tell me, so I won't make the same mistake in the future...

Comment: I'm curious where this array comes from.

Comment: @wezten if its array the you can get first element using `array[0]`

Comment: Basically, I have a form, and I do various validations on it - so I end up with a list of fields that have errors, but out of order, since there are different kinds of validations, and I would like to focus the first one.

Comment: @DipeshParmar: The OP said it's an array, and it's *not* in DOM order, and he wants the first entry *in DOM order*.

Comment: I assume the downvote is because this question is very broad. We need to see your code to understand it. Without this it wold be basically impossible to know which element could come first.

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar - I said that they are not in DOM order, but I would like the one that occurs the first in the DOM.

Comment: @wezten: For that, would the first in the *visual* order be sufficient? E.g., the one nearest the top/left?

Comment: @BenM - it definitely is possible - I can just iterate through the DOM, and stop when I hit an element in the list - but that will take ages and is not practical.

Comment: @wezten: How about using .get(0) or .first() as mentioned in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103810/how-do-i-get-first-element-rather-than-using-0-in-jquery ?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, yes it would, didn't think of that

Comment: @wezten: *"but that will take ages and is not practical"* It probably wouldn't take as long as you think, actually, and as this is in response to a user action, if you really want DOM order, it may well be the most practical way -- esp. as your need is limited to a specific form.

Comment: @jay - because that might give me the last DOM element on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860400/428724) that states that when you add with jQuery two elements, they will end up in document order.

So basically we can just do $().add(elementList).eq(0).

Comment: Ah, yes, and that's [clearly documented](http://api.jquery.com/add/): *"Do not assume that this method appends the elements to the existing collection in the order they are passed to the .add() method. When all elements are members of the same document, the resulting collection from .add() will be sorted in document order; that is, in order of each element's appearance in the document."* I wonder which is faster, this or my recursive search above (as jQuery has to do work, after all, to determine the order). Mind you, this is in response to a user action, unlikely to be speed-critical.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said *visual* order (rather than DOM order) is sufficient, you can do this:

```
var first, firstTop, firstLeft;
$.each(yourArray, function(index, element) {
    var pos = $(element).offset();
    if (!first ||
        (pos.top < firstTop) ||
        (pos.top === firstTop && pos.left < firstLeft)
       ) {
        first = element;
        firstTop = pos.top;
        firstLeft = pos.left;
    }
});
```

---

That said, I don't think doing a recursive descent on the DOM and stopping at the first element you find is really as much work as you think it is from your comment, esp. since you're only interested in elements within the form. Something along these lines:

```
function getFirstInDOM(list, root) {
    var node, found;
    for (node = root.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        // I assume you only care about elements, so skipping other nodes
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            if (list.indexOf(node) !== -1) {
                // Found
                return node;
            }
            found = getFirstInDOM(list, node);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/oSEjeXI/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/oSEjeXI/1/edit)